# SLT error: No columns found for table <table name>

Tags: slt

Our SLT (SAP Landscape Transformation) configuration fails with this error message:

> No columns found for table db2inst1.ASDF
>
> [image]

What are possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the database user has the required access rights as described in the security guide.
2. When using DB2 make sure to select DB6 (not DB2) and provide the correct table space name!